# Knockout pass filename to server

Tags: file-upload, knockout.js

I'm writing an application using Knockout.  I want the user to browse for a file and then I want to pass the filename to the server.  However, due to browser security issues, the path of the file is always c:\fakepath.

Does anyone one a way to get the filename to the server so it can get the file and upload it?  The reason I want to use the server to upload the file is because I'm storing the file using Amazon S3 and I want the server to do the connection.

Here's my binding:

```
<input type="file" name="talkFile" data-bind="value: $root.TalkFile">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout doesn't have a file binding. Either submit the file the old fashioned way or look into something like [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) for ajax files.

If you opt. to use ajax in your template, make sure the form wrapping is file element is a multipart encoding (enctype="multipart/form-data") and then you can add a custom binding.

I usually use this: 
Template

```
<input type="file" id="fileupload" name="image" data-bind="fileUpload : '.dropzone' " >
```

Custom binding

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.fileUpload = {
    init: function(el, valueAccessor, aba, mod){
        $(el).fileupload({
            dropZone: valueAccessor(), //this would be .dropzone
            url: '/upload/path,
            dataType: 'json',
            done: function (e, data) {                  
            }
        });
    }
};
```